# iOS: RestKit operation blocks not executing when I want them to

Tags: ios, ipad, grand-central-dispatch, restkit-0.20

I am using RestKit .20 to map two objects. The second object depends on the first. So the first operation is must take place before the second. Once the operation is complete the controller uses the model objects to display appropriate information in a table view.

The first object has a unique id which is used to form part of the url request to obtain the objects that attach to it. Its all working and the request are getting the info and performing the mapping correctly however the oder of operation is all wrong and I just can't get my head around it!

This is what I want to happen:

1. View loads and starts loading/mapping the first objects.
2. Once first objects are loaded second objects get loaded/mapped.
3. Table view reloads.

Heres what happens:

1. View loads up, loads table view.
2. operations get executed last and everytime a block operation executes then it reloads the data - not the solution I want but its the only way i could get it working.

Its hard for me to explain so heres some code: (I've omitted allot of un-relevant code)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad]; 
    [self loadFirstObjects];        
    //omitted code

}



- (void)loadFirstObjects {
    //omitted code

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
        self.pubRepos = mappingResult.array;
        [self loadSecondaryObjects];
    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", error);
    }];

    [operation start];
}

- (void)loadSecondObjects
{
    for (FirstObject *firstObject in firstObjects) {

        //Omitted code

        [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
            SecondObject *secondObject = [mappingResult.array objectAtIndex:0];

            [secondObjects setObject:secondObject forKey:secondObject.idNum];
            [table reloadData];
        } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", error);
        }];

        [operation start];

    }
}
```

So how do I get this working the way I want? I want to be able to perform the request/mapping first then load all the information into the table and update it. I need to constantly reload/map new data from the web service to be separate from reloading the table.

SO in other words, the biggest question here is: How do I control exactly when the operation blocks get executed?

Comment: "I'm a junior iOS programmer so play nice".... is it warning or a request .. LOL..!

Comment: Requesting forgiveness in bad "stackoverflow etiquette" :D :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this rather easily is to use `dispatch_group`. Your `-loadSecondObjects` method might look like this:

```
- (void)loadSecondObjects
{
    dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

    for (FirstObject *firstObject in firstObjects) {
        // Omitted code
        dispatch_group_enter(group);
        [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
            SecondObject *secondObject = [mappingResult.array objectAtIndex:0];
            [secondObjects setObject:secondObject forKey:secondObject.idNum];
            dispatch_group_leave(group);
        } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", error);
            dispatch_group_leave(group);
        }];

        [operation start];
    }

    dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [table reloadData];
    });
}
```

In essence, what's going on here is that you're using the `dispatch_group` as a convenient counter with the added feature that you can set up a block to execute when the counter next hits zero.  The counter starts at 0. For every second-object load you begin, you increment the counter (by calling `dispatch_group_enter`), then for every second-object load that completes (or fails), you decrement the counter (by calling `dispatch_group_leave`). When the counter hits 0, the block you set up with `dispatch_group_notify` will be executed (and you can know at that time that all your second-object load operations are complete.)

PS: Since I didn't see any retain/release-ish calls in your code, I'm assuming you're using ARC. If you're not, then you'll need to `dispatch_release` the group.